# Sum and group data from object

Tags: javascript, object

As title , I have a problem with processing data

example data :

```
[
 {detail: { '60': 300, '80': 200 }},
 {detail: { '60': 100, '68': 222 }}
]
```

how do i process those data become like this :

```
"60" : {
 "sum" : 400,  // value
 "count" : 2
},
"80" : {
 "sum" : 200,
 "count" : 1
},
"68" : {
 "sum" : 222,
 "count" : 1
},
```

Comment: where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `Object.entries` and `Array.forEach`

Comment: @NinaScholz He obviously needs one of your reduces ;)

Comment: here is one: [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: `for` + `for ... in ...` + some math. Give it a shot...

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
 {detail: { '60': 300, '80': 200 }},
 {detail: { '60': 100, '68': 222 }}
];

let result = {};

data.forEach( d => {
  let currentobj = d.detail
  Object.keys(currentobj).forEach( n=>{
    if(result[n]){
      result[n].sum += currentobj[n];
      result[n].count ++;
    }else{
      result[n] = {
      sum : currentobj[n],
      count : 1}
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
```